# Stucked in loop during the deployment in Render

Tags: typescript, deployment, backend, render, mern

I have this problem where it always throws a Failed whenever it reaches to node dist/server.js and i noticed that it loop, I doubled check my directory structure and it seems well structured.

What does the causes of this?

anyone?

> Cloning from https://github.com/Mana1010/Keep-Me
> Checking out commit 5a08087e18c29e9892b658e61ddfa437edefc5c0 in branch master
> Using Node version 20.11.1 (default)
> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
> Running build command 'npm install bcrypt cookie-parser cors dotenv express express-async-handler helmet jsonwebtoken mongoose morgan'...
> added 168 packages, and audited 169 packages in 8s
> 17 packages are looking for funding
> run `npm fund` for details
> found 0 vulnerabilities
> Uploading build...
> Build uploaded in 8s
> Build successful 
> Deploying...
> Using Node version 20.11.1 (default)
> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
> Running 'npm run start'
> start
> node dist/server.js
> Using Node version 20.11.1 (default)
> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
> Common ways to troubleshoot your deploy: https://docs.render.com/troubleshooting-deploys
> Running 'npm run start'
> start
> node dist/server.js
> Using Node version 20.11.1 (default)
> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
> Running 'npm run start'
> start
> node dist/server.js

I tried to follow in tutorial from yt but still no luck:(